# Is it possible to use an Arduino Sketch as a C++ program?

Tags: c++, arduino, raspbian

I know some modifications will need to be made but can I convert an Arduino Sketch and compile it to run on a Raspbian System as a C++ program? I am looking to use a [modbus library](https://github.com/andresarmento/modbus-arduino) from Arduino to output data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you kind of can use your arduino sketch into **Raspbian** but you must use some libs. I recommend you look at this [site](http://wiringpi.com/), the only change is the pinout. WiringPi lib is a PIN based GPIO access library written in C for the BCM2835, BCM2836 and BCM2837, so you can use almost every function like arduino but in Raspberry. Also the way it will be compiled and executed will change. I recommend you learn a little bit of linux and how to compile C++/C code by command line.

There is some example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <wiringPi.h>

using namespace std;


/* Defines */
#define LED  2

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (wiringPiSetup() == -1) {
    cout << "Unable configure wiringPi! Exiting..." << endl;
    return 1;
  }

  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);

  while (1 < 2) {
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
    delay(500);
  }

  return 0;
}
```